# Setting affinity for virus protection on workstations - best practice?

Tags: anti-virus, best-practices

Despite the modern virus protection is based on prevention by scanning network traffic and by real-time protection, many companies still have policies, that full scans must be performed regularly. Since hard drives are getting bigger and bigger, this kind of scans takes longer and eats up resources. Also, if users turns off their computers when leaving office, the scans must be scheduled at times when they should be using the computer for something more meaningful.

I've come to a solution, that it's best to make a compromise by setting virus scanner process ProcessorAffinity to just one or two cores, allowing the user to use the rest of the resources. That allows to fulfill the strict policy of regular scans without frustrating the users with the slowdowns, not to mention the unnecessary problem reports caused by it.

I don't have any problem setting this up: I can easily automate it by deploying a scheduled task currently triggered by user logon, e.g. for F-Secure (*Scanner Manager* process):

```
schtasks /create /tn "F-Secure Affinity" \
  /tr "PowerShell '$Process = Get-Process fssm32; $Process.ProcessorAffinity=2'" \
  /sc onlogon /delay 0001:00 /ru System
```

Here, the affinity is set when the user logs in, since before that there's no other need for the resources on regular workstations.

I'm just curious whether this is best practice or has any disadvantages.

- Is this giving malware a potential head start? Is this a notable risk?
- Should  I have different triggers than logon and should I set it back after the scan finishes?
- Is there a better way to achieve the goal of satisfying both: the company policy and the users?

Comment: Seems like a decent idea to me.  When I've worked at places that required full scans, I scheduled them for middle of the night and set up the workstations to boot, scan, then power off when done.

Comment: Scanning at night is a good option too. In my case it's not possible for other reasons, but I'd like to keep this open for wider discussion. However, with huge hard drives combined with advanced heuristics the scans may last extremely long for some users, so night time scans aren't universally working solution, either.

Comment: This problem was solved later in the 2015 when I got the chance to decide how to arrange the overall virus protection there and got rid of these scheduled scans. I'm still curious if there are other aspects I haven't thought of.

Answer (score 3):

While an appealing idea at first, you should consider than antivirus scans are generally bound by disk I/O performance, rather then CPU speed.

In other word, with PC using classical mechanical disk, change antivirus affinity is not going to have a significant impact on user experience: its PC will remain slow, due to very poor IOPS provided by the underlying storage.

Comment: Good point, this must be taken into account. Currently, the 100% CPU usage has been the bottleneck and changing the affinity actually has had positive effects on user experience... wait, my UX sample group _is_ on SSD. I need to collect more data.

Comment: Yes, you definitely need to take classic HDDs into account.

Comment: But only when they are as system drives and the scanning is currently on the system drive. In addition to SSDs, a system scanning through a huge _separated_ storage drive can be well responsive, too.